# C# Update labels on custom progress bar windows form

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I'm creating a form which simulates a progress bar.

The form has a progress bar, a label with a title and another label showing the progress percentage.

The idea is that before starting a loop I create an instance of the form using that  loop's element count. Each iteration of the loop a method is called to update the progress bar, and the percentage label.

The progress bar is being updated fine, but the title and percentage labels are not being updated. I've read that's because everything is executed in the same thread, and the UI is not being updated.

This is my code:

**Main program**

```
...

MyProgressBar_Form pb = new MyProgressBar_Form("Test of progress bar", selectionBudget.Count);
pb.Show();

foreach (SelectedObject obj in selectionBudget) {
    pb.meterProgress();

    ...

}

pb.Close();

...
```

**Form class**

```
public partial class MyProgressBar_Form : Form {

    public MyProgressBar_Form(string title, int elems) {
        InitializeComponent();

        titleLbl.Text = title;

        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = elems;
        progressBar1.Step = 1;

        this.Refresh();
    }

    public void meterProgress() {

        if (progressBar1.Value < progressBar1.Maximum) {
            progressBar1.Value++;

            double percentage = Math.Round((double)(progressBar1.Value / progressBar1.Maximum * 100), 2);
            progressLbl.Text = $"{percentage}%";

            this.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Problem]

Comment: Try using a `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Also, can you post the code inside your main program so that I can suggest a better approach?

Answer (score -1):

Try Application.DoEvents() inside the loop.

Comment: Arrggh! No. Never do that. `DoEvents()` is only there for backward compatibility with VB6. It's an excellent way to introduce bugs in to your code that are almost impossible to diagnose and therefore fix.

Comment: @Enigmativity it's dirty, but it's quick and it works. For a form that contains nothing more than a ProgressBar, there are not many things that could go wrong.

Comment: It's not dirty. It's dangerous. It messes with the standard winforms message pump. It should never ever be used.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have used it many times in the past, when I didn't know any better, and nothing bad happened to me. No puppies or kittens were harmed. It also served well the classic VB community, and still does (believe it or not VB6 is still used today).

Comment: I feel it's a bit like eating raw chicken. You can do it a fair bit, but when you get sick you get sick bad.

Comment: Jeff Atwood [once said](https://blog.codinghorror.com/is-doevents-evil/) that abandoning DoEvents in favor of multithreading is for tough guys who grow hair on their chest, by losing hair on their heads. :-)

Comment: That whole article was saying that `DoEvents` better than hard-core threading - which is possibly a good argument. But using `BackgroundWorker`, or `Tasks`, or `Observables`, etc, are not hard-core threading. Those should be favoured over `DoEvents`.

Comment: All these are good, but come with a learning curve, and don't prevent you from mutating shared state and shooting yourself in the foot. Then you'll put locks everywhere and deadlock yourself. If you don't know what you are doing, DoEvents is not really worse than the others (and it's quicker to use).

Comment: Arrghh. `DoEvents` is eminently evil. The others are just hard.